# Android Bugsense

Tags: android, bugsense

I have integrated bugsense-1.9.jar in my project and try to log the exceptions to bugsense.Here is my code:

```
try {
           // your code
           int a = 1/0; // this will raise an exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
           BugSenseHandler.log("Divide by zero exception", e);
           //throw new RuntimeException("exception requested by user");
           Log.i("errrr logg:",""+e);
           BugSenseHandler.readLogs(); 
        }
```

Its showing me {"data": [], "error": null} instead of error logs shown below

```
Looking for exceptions in: /data/data/com.Narolainfotech.MyShortSaleScore/files
07-09 16:59:04.561: D/BugSenseHandler(15399): Found 0 stacktrace(s)
07-09 16:59:04.561: D/BugSenseHandler(15399): Transmitting log data
07-09 16:59:04.571: D/BugSenseHandler(15399): Transmitting stack trace:java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
07-09 16:59:04.571: D/BugSenseHandler(15399):   at          android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)

07-09 16:59:22.781: D/BUGSENSE(15399): {"data": [], "error": null}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

ReadLogs are only available for Entreprise plan. Do you got one ?

Be sure to add to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `READ_LOGS` permission was limited only to rooted devices since Jelly bean.